# Post/Redirect/Get: Get is called multiple times

Tags: http, sinatra

I have a webpage which has a form that is submitted via POST. This POST-route processes some data and redirects the User to a GET route. The problem: The GET route is called multiple times, usually 3 times. So three GET's are fired and the user see's the first GET request. The other two GET requests I can just see on my logs.

Occasionally it even happens that the GET is called more than three times...

(Of course the POST route is just called once...)

By the way I'm using JRuby/JRack/Sinatra on Jetty (-> Google App Engine.) The problem happens locally and remotely.

Philip

Comment: I've seen that the response of the server *after* the POST request is a 302, c.f. here http://www.gittr.com/index.php/archive/details-of-sinatras-redirect-helper/  I changed the code to 303 but the problem stays the same...

Comment: I was able to debug the problem much more: In the GET response HTML there is a Javascript that loads an image from the server with a relative url. (/image/some_image.png) If I remove the code that loads the image the problem doesn't happen. Actually when responding to the image-GET the server sends some 304 stuff (matching sequence number to request)... Anyways I can solve the problem by making the URL absolute and including a host name...

Comment: It may help to issue the POST via a command line client like cURL to (a) verify that your client is not sending multiple GET requests, and (b) do the POST and GET requests separately to verify that none of the surplus GETs are being triggered by the POST request. You can use `curl -vL` to verbosely print requests issued and follow redirects, and ctrl-z & `fg` (if on linux) to pause between POST and GET to check your server logs.

Answer (score 3):

I have had that same issue in my code before (although different platform).  It turned out to be elements in the page referencing the same url as the page.  I had 1 broken image and 2 ignored css files that had been set to the parent page.

If it's the same kind of issue you can use Firebug's net tab to verify and debug.

Comment: I assume it's slightly different, Firebug just shows that everthings is normal...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without seeing the code, but in most cases a script will continue to execute after a call to a redirect function. Try returning from your method immediately after calling redirect_to.

Comment: Sinatra is very high level, so it leaves the function after calling redirect. As one would expect the HTTP Message Body is empty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sinatra - in a Rails controller, returning from the action would terminate the controller. There should be some equivalent at a higher abstraction level, something like exit(0) to terminate a PHP script.

Comment: I just checked it to be sure, but a return statement after a redirect in Sinatra makes no difference because it is not reached. But it is similiar, a return statement in Sinatra finishes the response, after that the instance can be used to handle the next request.

Answer (score -3):

There is a logical bug in your code. Fix it.